# Is there a function to calculate Sample Size for random intercept model in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, statistical-power

I am new to random effects and am trying to understand sample size/power/ effect size calculations.

Let's say I have a dataset with 52 subjects who reported anxiety outcomes at four points in time. So there are a total of 208 observations. I wrote a model (mod1 below) which allowed the intercept to vary by subject.

```
mod1 <- lmer(anxiety ~ time * condition * dis + white + Age +  
    Sex + Edu + Medicare + ins + Pri + Noins + Other + (1|subject), data = df)
```

I'm not totally sure how to think about calculating power since I have subjects and their observations. I'd like to see an effect size of 0.15 at alpha 0.05, and Power at .80.  Is there a way to do this in R? I know there are several ways to consider power depending on the type of test done.  I have tried the following where "u" refers to the number of coefficients in the model. I wasn't sure if an interaction term changed the"u", but kept it ay 12 to be more conservative:

```
pwr.f2.test(u = 12, f2 = 0.15/(1 - 0.15), sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8)
```

which yielded the following:

```
 Multiple regression power calculation 

          u = 12
          v = 96.16218
         f2 = 0.1764706
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
```

where sample size would be: n = u + v + 1 = 109. First, is this a correct approach for a random intercept model, and secondly does the 109 refer to the individual subjects, or all observations of the subjects.

packages:  lme4 , pwr

Comment: Others can chime in, I've generally had to do simulations which is incredibly computationally intensive, i.e. over the course of a few days running on a desktop PC CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How about ballpark estimates? Any way to estimate if 52 subjects each observed at four points in time would comfortably be in an acceptable sample size range?

Comment: Long ago I asked this question about GEE specifically https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339873/effective-sample-size-reduction-for-correlated-data-analyses. Also, you can take a conservative approach of estimating the power for the F-test using the between-within degrees of freedom, and an estimate of the residual error for average cluster effects.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a closely related question. Though my answer didn't suffice, the paper linked is very informative. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350827/the-statistical-power-of-cluster-level-predictors-in-linear-mixed-effects-models/350858#350858

Comment: [`longpower::lmmpower`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/longpower/index.html) and [`simr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/index.html) come to mind.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This has been very helpful. It looks as if the longpower ::lmmpower may work, but i'm still scratching my head about how to code it correctly with my example. Do I need to consider time between observations, and random intercept variance? I came across a couple of good descriptions which i'm now reading: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/longpower/vignettes/longpower.html and https://rdrr.io/cran/longpower/man/lmmpower.html