# When using both Sattertwaite degrees of freedom adjustment AND sandwich estimator of the covariance, how do they interact?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, generalized-least-squares, robust-standard-error, satterthwaite

In longitudinal experimental trials, where typically (relatively) small sample number of participants are examined, two solutions are proposed to address two kinds of issues:

- robust estimator of the covariance - in case the model was misspecified and some assumptions were not fully met. This happens typically when other than unstructured residual covariance is used - due to convergence issues - and we replace it with some simpler structure (thus imposing some artificial - even if reasonable - constraint).
- Satterthwaite or Kenward-Roger adjustment for the degrees of freedom in small samples, also addressing the problems with potential heteroscedasticity (related to the previous one) - like in the Welch t- test (also called Welch-Satterthwaite).

While the Kenward-Roger cannot be used (for some unknown to me reason) with the sandwich estimator of covariance, the Satterthwaite is often use together with it sandwich.

I'm wondering how they work. For example let's use the GLS estimation apples to the repeated observations analyzed via general linear model.

I thought, the GLS will calculate the covariance based on some assumed degrees of freedom. For example, "residual" or "Satterthwaite" ones. So, the covariance matrix would be calculated with them "in mind".

But not we personally impose the sandwich algorithm, which itself alters the GLS estimation.

My question is - will the Satterthwaite degrees of freedom be somehow "merged" with the sandwich?

Or differently, if I provide both settings to a statistical package, how they will be used togerhet? At which stage each will be employed in the final calculations? I don't ask for a concrete package, R or SAS, I ask about the common mathematical way.

I don't need strict formulas - just approximate explanation will be fine.

I made exemplary calculations in R and it turns out, that both Satterthwaite adjustment AND the choice of covariance estimator affect the degrees of freedom. But which is one is first when giving them? Is Satterthwaite secondary to sandwich or vice versa?

Comment: Possibly related - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350827/the-statistical-power-of-cluster-level-predictors-in-linear-mixed-effects-models/350858#350858 especially https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3987820/